# Preprocessor defines and macros for m68k?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

We are failing a build under [Debian's testing/build infrastructure](https://buildd.debian.org/status/fetch.php?pkg=libcrypto%2B%2B&arch=m68k&ver=5.6.3-4&stamp=1459687264) for m68k:

```
config.h:29:3: error: #error "IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN is set, but __BYTE_ORDER__  does not equal __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__"
 # error "IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN is set, but __BYTE_ORDER__  does not equal __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__"
```

The fix is easy, but I need to know the preprocessor defines for the platform. I don't have a machine with the architecture, so I can't dump them with `gcc -dM -E - </dev/null | sort`.

Could someone please provide the preprocessor output for the m68k?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to kill time, you could build a cross-compiler for that platform. If you *only* care about that one specific flag, try adding this test to your `configure.ac`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

enum {
  ENDIAN_UNKNOWN,
  ENDIAN_BIG,
  ENDIAN_LITTLE,
  ENDIAN_BIG_WORD,   /* Middle-endian, Honeywell 316 style */
  ENDIAN_LITTLE_WORD /* Middle-endian, PDP-11 style */
};

int endianness(void)
{
  union
  {
    uint32_t value;
    uint8_t data[sizeof(uint32_t)];
  } number;

  number.data[0] = 0x00;
  number.data[1] = 0x01;
  number.data[2] = 0x02;
  number.data[3] = 0x03;

  switch (number.value)
  {
  case UINT32_C(0x00010203): return ENDIAN_BIG;
  case UINT32_C(0x03020100): return ENDIAN_LITTLE;
  case UINT32_C(0x02030001): return ENDIAN_BIG_WORD;
  case UINT32_C(0x01000302): return ENDIAN_LITTLE_WORD;
  default:                   return ENDIAN_UNKNOWN;
  }
}
```